# Why I getting error "bash: manage.py: command not found"?

Tags: heroku, migrate

I'm trying to deploy Django project on Heroku. The Postgres db was created by default. And by the instructions, I should make migrate:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

And I so like Heroku connecting and then:

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ XXXXXXXXXXX... up, run.4060 (Free)
bash: manage.py: command not found
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Do you have a `manage.py` in the root of your repository?

Comment: Also, are you entirely sure that you're running `heroku run python manage.py migrate` (with `python`), not `heroku run manage.py migrate`? The error message makes it look like you're trying to run `manage.py` as a command directly, not as an argument to `python`.

Comment: yes, When I type "ls" I can see manage.py.

Comment: I'm sure that I type with "python"

Comment: maybe something else?

Comment: 'When I type "ls" I can see manage.py'—on your local machine? Or via `heroku run ls`? Or interactively, from `heroku run bash`?

Comment: I can see manage.py on my local machine and via "heroku run ls" it also works.

Comment: and on bash also

Comment: If you run `heroku run bash`, then from that interactive terminal run `python manage.py migrate`, what happens?

Comment: migrations runing

Comment: and everything OK

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure `heroku run python manage.py migrate` should work then. If not, try updating your Heroku CLI.

Comment: I run "heroku run python3 manage.py migrate" and it works now! Chris, thank you so much for your help! It was also helping me.

Comment: `python` should work as well as `python3`, but I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same error, changing it from

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

to

```
heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
```

did it for me.

Comment: My question is why python manage.py works whereas manage.py without python interpreter does not work ? please explain